# macOS Catalina - Getting SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED with Python 3

Tags: python, ssl, certificate, python3, macos-catalina

I'm getting `SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED - certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate` error when I try to connect a service hosted through HTTPS. Many have proposed executing the command `Install Certificates.command`, which was mentioned to be located on `/Applications/Python\ 3.7/`, as the fix but I do not have that file in my `Applications` on my machine. How can I fix this issue which looks like specific to macOS as I do not have any issues on my Windows machine, and some others mentioned that there is no problem on Linux as well.

p.s. I'm using the `Python 3` which comes with `macOS Catalina`. Have not installed `Python 3` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for help with this question. 
I am having the same problem with macOS Catalina and Python 3. I reinstalled python 3.7.4 from the Python site where the installer includes a step to install certificates. However, I am not sure how to verify that they have been installed correctly.

I am using MMQGIS and a google api to geocode addresses and continue get this error after installing certificates: 
Failure connecting to maps.googleapis.com: : 0 addresses geocoded